# Using lm() within lapply with ifelse condition

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I am trying to run several regressions using `lapply`. I want to use an `ifelse` condition to differentiate between which regression to run. However, when I use `ifelse` the output is not an `lm` object. I am attaching the code for reproducing my problem. Please help.

```
attach(iris)

names.list = c('a','b','c')

models.work = lapply(names.list,
                    function(f)
                      {
                      lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris)
                     })

models.not.work = lapply(names.list,
                     function(f)
                     {
                      ifelse(1==1,
                      lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris),
                      lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris)
                      )
                     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifelse` can't return a model object in this case. Use a normal `if`-`else` clause, that should do it.

```
attach(iris)

names.list = c('a','b','c')
models.not.work = lapply(names.list,
                         function(f)
                         {
                           if(1==1){
                                  lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris)}else{
                                  lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris)
                                  }

                         })


#output

> models.not.work[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     6.5262      -0.2234
```

Comment: Accepted because this is most relevant to the problem I have at hand.

Answer (score 2):

`ifelse` says it returns:

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
>   "class") as test

where `test` is the input.  Your input is `1==1` (which by the way you can just use `TRUE`) which has input length of 1.  So ifelse will return something of length 1.  `lm` returns a list so it will only return the first element from that list.  Which happens to be the coefficients.

`ifelse` is not what you want to use here. It's not clear what you're actually trying to do but there is most likely a better way to achieve your actual goal.

You might just want to use a normal `if` statement if you're manually cycling through the elements anyways.  There is probably a better way to do it if you explain what you're actually trying to do though.